# ML.NET problem (Microsoft.ML.SearchSpace)

Tags: ml.net, xamarin.essentials

Why this error and warning keep showing?, I don't even have Microsoft.ML.SearchSpace or Microsoft.ML.StandardTrainers from references and I can't find those from NuGet Pangake Manager. This only happens when I install ML.NET.

Error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Can not resolve reference: `Microsoft.ML.SearchSpace`, referenced by `Microsoft.ML.StandardTrainers`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Microsoft.ML.SearchSpace`, or remove the reference to `Microsoft.ML.StandardTrainers`.  Chicken_Meat_Freshness_Checker

Warning:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Numerics.Vectors" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
"System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll].
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll".
System.Numerics.Vectors
References which depend on "System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
C:\Users\Alhen Miller.nuget\packages\system.numerics.tensors\8.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Numerics.Tensors.dll
Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\Alhen Miller.nuget\packages\system.numerics.tensors\8.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Numerics.Tensors.dll".
C:\Users\Alhen Miller.nuget\packages\system.numerics.tensors\8.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Numerics.Tensors.dll
C:\Users\Alhen Miller.nuget\packages\microsoft.ml.cpumath\3.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.ML.CpuMath.dll
C:\Users\Alhen Miller.nuget\packages\microsoft.ml\3.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.ML.Data.dll
C:\Users\Alhen Miller.nuget\packages\microsoft.ml\3.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.ML.KMeansClustering.dll
C:\Users\Alhen Miller.nuget\packages\microsoft.ml\3.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.ML.PCA.dll
C:\Users\Alhen Miller.nuget\packages\microsoft.ml\3.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.ML.StandardTrainers.dll
C:\Users\Alhen Miller.nuget\packages\microsoft.ml\3.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.ML.Transforms.dll
C:\Users\Alhen Miller.nuget\packages\microsoft.ml.imageanalytics\3.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics.dll  Chicken_Meat_Freshness_Checker

I tried to open my project to text editor but theres nothing about Microsoft.ML.SearchSpace.